# Way of determining the size of the container

Tags: c++, iterator

Is there any other way to determine size of the container than :

```
//those are valid iterators from a container
BidIt begin;
BidIt end;
std::size_t size = 0;

while (begin != end)
{//Here throug iterating I'm getting adventually the correct size
   ++size;
   ++begin;
}
```

but I wonder if I could check size of this container by for example substracting addresses of this iterators or something like this.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what type of containers are you using? Is BidIt a templated type?

Comment: Most of the standard containers have a size method built in!

Comment: @Martin you can't see it from my example (my fault) but I need to determine the size withing a fnc which takes only iterators to this container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) function.  Note that if your iterators are *not* [RandomAccessIterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/) the distance function will use basically the same method of calculating the distance that you've shown.

Comment: @Martin: Then it just subtracts them.  I only added that last bit to let @A-ha know that the looping method isn't so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You can add an extra member 'size' to the BidIt type and update it whenever a insert or delete operation is performed on the container and also a getter method to get the size.